# Direct flights between cities with the same name

Tags: air-travel, where-on-earth, factoids

One can fly from [London (YXU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_International_Airport) to [London (LHR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Airport) (via Toronto), from [Glasgow (GGW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Valley_County_Airport) to [Glasgow (GLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Airport) (multiple stops), or from [Moscow (PUW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullman%E2%80%93Moscow_Regional_Airport) to [Moscow (SVO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheremetyevo_International_Airport) (via Seattle).  There are others (Sydney, Manchester, Portland, ...; I'm not aiming for a complete list here).  For trains, once a week, there was a [**direct** train which stops first at Frankfurt (am Main) and then at Frankfurt (an der Oder)](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=91e2cd&date=07.02.2020) (until pandemic and war stopped this train).

But are there, or have there ever been, any direct scheduled **flights** between two cities of the same name?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there had at one point been non-stop service between Saint John, New Brunswick, Canada, and St. John's, Newfoundland, Canada.  But the names aren't quite identical, and there's no such service currently.

Comment: You can add Sydney Nova Scotia and Sydney Australia to your name pairs. Multiple stops.

Comment: @KateGregory I didn't know about Sydney, Nova Scotia.  There are also Manchester (MHT) and Manchester (MAN), or the three-way Portland (PWM), Portland (PTJ), and Portland (PDX).  PWM-PDX is probably the most likely "direct same name" of any pair I've found yet, but no direct flights there either.  But my list is not meant to be exhaustive.

Comment: San Jose, CA, USA, and San Jose, Costa Rica is a pair that sometimes comes up when you hear about people booking tickets to the wrong airport.  Sydney and Manchester also.  Both Sydney in Canada and Manchester in the US seem to have no international flights, so they are unlikely ever to have had direct flights to their namesake airports.

Comment: There's direct flights from DCA (Arlington, VA) to Dallas/Fort Worth, where Arlington TX is right in between, does that count?

Comment: Pretty sure you can find a bus from [Kansas City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_City,_Kansas) to [Kansas City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_City,_Missouri), but I don't know if that counts.

Comment: @KateGregory Sydney is a classic.  Once every other year someone makes the mistake.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'd read one such story but a quick search does turn up a few more! https://www.google.com/search?q=ends+up+in+wrong+sydney+nova+scotia

Comment: Identical question in this forum https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=551205

Comment: I guess **Melbourne** and **St Petersburg** are two usual examples of this (no non-stops though, I'd guess).

Comment: Portland OR to Portland ME?

Comment: @abligh: Already mentioned in gerrit's comment above - no direct flights between the two.

Comment: Saint-Jean, Terre-Neuve and Saint-Jean, Nouveau Brunswick have the same name in French. I'm sure if you look at names in Latin, you can find many places with the same name.

Comment: @KateGregory Apart from Sydney and Sydney, there is also [Sidney (SDY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney%E2%80%93Richland_Municipal_Airport), just spelt slightly differently.

Comment: @Mark you can also walk between those cities.

Comment: Whilst not quite meeting the criteria, United Airlines recently launched flights from SFO (located about 3 miles south of Brisbane, California, USA) to BNE (Brisbane, Queensland, Australia)

Answer (score 72):

Alaska Airlines flies nonstop from San Jose, CA USA to San Jose del Cabo in Mexico.

Comment: I was actually in line for a San Jose flight last December, only to realise that I actually need the del Cabo one :)

Comment: @JonathanReez Good catch! One reads occasionally about some hapless traveler who wants to fly to one San Jose, and carelessly buys a ticket for the other. Unlike you, they might not be stopped at boarding, but could (and sometimes do) end up by surprise in a different town.

Comment: Reminds me of the British couple who thought they found a good deal on a flight to Birmingham and ended up in Alabama.

Comment: Is it pronounced the same in the US and in Mexico?

Comment: @NeanDerThal Depends on how well you know Spanish

Comment: @NeanDerThal I think the US one is typically pronounced like it would be in Spanish, so besides it normally carrying an American accent, yes they would be pronounced the same.

Comment: "San Jose" and "San Jose del Cabo" are not the same name. This would be like someone posting an answer about Alex, OK USA to Alexandria, IN USA via Alexander, AL USA  (if such a flight existed).

Comment: @GlenYates or my co-worker who was excited that the company was sending her to Rome only to find out it was in New York.

Comment: @Nij Yes, the formal (complete) names are different. Many travelers and residents, however, refer to the Mexican city as San Jose.

Comment: There was a person who wanted a flight to Oakland but ended up in Auckland instead https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1985-04-02-mn-19265-story.html

Comment: Not quite the same, but an acquaintance took his wife to Paris, and his secretary booked them a table at the Eiffel Tower restaurant. In Toronto :-)

Comment: People seem to mix-up "Switzerland" and "Sweden" as a commonplace, too

Comment: @Fattie or Austria vs. Australia

Comment: true that, @HagenvonEitzen !  I once muddled those two in making a long-distance phone call in the old days, and accidentally woke up an innkeeper in the wrong country :)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf another classic is Sydney (Australia) vs. Sydney (Nova Scotia).

Comment: @Fattie: Switzerland vs Sweden might be a more common mix-up in other languages, e.g. Spanish where they are "Suiza" and "Suecia" respectively

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, `Many travelers and residents, however, refer to the Mexican city as San Jose`, I've been there and most of the residents call it simply Los Cabos. There are hundreds of San Jose cities in Latin America and ambiguity of using *San Jose* makes it unusable.

Comment: They might; the whole area (and the big airport near San Jose del Cabo - there's a smaller airport in Cabo San Lucas) are often referred-to that way. But if they want to distinguish between the two cities they use "Cabo" and "San Jose."

Comment: As David said, as a traveler to Cabo, the locals will refer to the two cities as the city of Cabo (or Cabo San Lucas) and the city of San Jose (they drop the del Cabo) when speaking to you. Even tough there are many San Joses in Mexico, where you are plays a role in which one they are referring. If you ask a taxi driver to take you to San Jose, they will assume you mean the local one. Just like someone in Texas talking about Arlington. If they don’t mean the one in Texas, they will say both city and state in their conversation (ex. “I am driving to Arlington, Virginia”).

Comment: @DeanF. Readers outside the United States might be unaware that a drive from Texas to Arlington, Virginia will be somewhere between roughly 1200 and 2100 km, comparable to driving from France to Athens.

Answer (score 30):

Newark, NJ to Newark, DE by Amtrak train.

5:15 PMNewark Penn Station
    Acela Express 2167 towards Washington Union Station
6:27 PM
6:40 PMWilmington Station
    Wilmington/Newark Line 3257 towards Newark
6:59 PMNewark
(Newark, Delaware)

Direct flight from EWR (Newark, NJ) to ILG Greater Wilmington Area (7 miles from Newark, DE)
https://www.flights.com/flights/wilmington-ilg-to-newark-ewr/

Comment: Is it the same name if it's pronounced differently, as is the case here?

Comment: A few more Amtrak connections (42 Pennsylvanian, 30 Capital Limited, 6 California Zephyr, and 524 Capitol Corridor), and you can pass through Newark, CA. No station there, though, so you’d have to get off in adjacent Fremont. Or continue through to San Jose and hop a plane for @ajd’s answer.

Comment: Your link shows that are *aren't* any flights from EWR to ILG, so this doesn't seem to qualify.  And the question specifies "flights", so the train doesn't count either.

Comment: Oh well.  They really should have a flight

Comment: If trains did count, the Amtrak Cascades stops at Vancouver, WA and Vancouver, BC.

Comment: @NateEldredge but is it nonstop?

Comment: @Trish: No, but neither is the Frankfurt(main)-Frankfurt(oder) train cited in the question.  And even for flights, the question does specify *direct* rather than *nonstop* (i.e. it's okay if the flight stops in between, so long as the flight number stays the same and you don't have to change planes).

Comment: I was confused how that could be a train journey, until I realised DE is Delaware, not Deutschland. :)

Comment: @user253751 A 2 hour train ride from NJ to Deutschland would be a nice surprise indeed.  A two-point spherical intersection tunnel, perhaps?

Comment: And nobody actually from the area is at risk of confusing NuErk with New-Ark. ;)

Comment: @user253751: I had a similar surprise when reading Nate's comment and thinking there couldn't be a train from (Western) Australia to Canada. Then I realised that WA was probably the US state of Washington.

Answer (score 22):

## Funny start?

Springfield SFY (MA) to Springfield SPI (IL) doesn't result in any connection for my booking advisor, neither to Springfield SGF (MO) nor Springfield VSF (VT). Neither does any other combination yield results, nor does Marshall MLL (AK) to the Marshall Islands MAJ nor St. Petersburg PIE (FL) to St. Petersburg/Leningrad LED (Russia)<sup>too bad, we could have listened to the song of the same name on the flight</sup>, nor could any combination of Newcastle/New Castle to New Castle be found.

## 4

To get from Alexandria AEX (LA, USA) to Alexandria HBE (Egypt) it takes 3 to 4 stops, so sadly that's out. Most [ancient Alexandrias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_founded_by_Alexander_the_Great) lack airports.

## 3

Glasgow GLA (Scotland) to Glasgow GCW (MT) has 3 stops. As is Trinidad (TTD) to Trinidad-Tobago, a country, using Port of Spain POS as a mark. Or Armenia AXM in Colombia to Yereven EVN in Armenia.

## 2

From Lebanon LEB (NH), it's 2 stops to Beirut BEI in *Lebanon*, so... kinda on/off the mark again? But remember Newcastle? Newcastle NCL (England) connects with Newcastle NTL (Australia) via 2 stops. Melbournde MEL (Australia) to Melbourne MLB (FL) has, once again, 2 stops. Roma RMA (Australia) to Roma ROM (Italy) usually has 2 or 3 stops.

More 2 stop: La Paz LPB (Bolivia) to La Paz LAP (Mexico). Sydney YQY (NS) to Sydney SYD (Australia). Augusta AGS (GA) to Augusta AUG (ME). Aberdeen ABZ (Scotland) to Aberdeen ABR (SD). Kandahar KDH (Afganistan) to Alexandria HBE (Egypt), because Kandahar is one of the 20-something Alexandrias. Or Kandahar KDH to Khujand LBD (Tajikistan), also founded as... Alexandria. Or from Khujand LBD to Termez TMJ (Uzbekistan)...

## 1

Kingston KIN (Jamaica) to Kingston YGK (ON, Canada) is 1 or 2 stops, we get better!
Same for London LON (England) to London YXU (ON), 1 stop and occasional 2 stops, as is San Jose SJC (CA) to San Jose SJO (Costa Rica), as is from San Jose SJO to San Jose SJD (Mexico), or Santiago SCL (Chile) to Santiago STI (Dominican Republic), or Manchester NHT (NH) to Manchester MAN (England) or Rochester ROC (NY) to Rochester RST (MN). Or Manhattan MHK (KS) to Manhattan, New York NYC (NY), landing in EWR or JFK.

But to get from San Jose SJC (CA) to San Jose SJD (Mexico) or Columbus CMH to Columbus CSG (GA), it's always 1 stop, Again, a little better on the track. Same for Washington (DC) WAS to Washington (State) using SEA. Or Saint John YSJ (Canada) to St.John's YYT (Canada). And another case of former-Alexandrias: Kandahar KDH to Herat HEA (both Afganistan) via Kabul.

## my winner is:

- Santa Cruz (de la Palma) SPC Santa Cruz (de la Tenerife) TCI (both Spain) - which is a 30 mintues **nonstop** domestic flight in Spain.

#### Honorable mention

Kaliningrad (since 1996: Korolyov) to Kaliningrad KGD (formerly: Königsberg) in Kaliningrad Oblast would have been a nonstop flight... from Moscow SVO.

The mad Alexandria-dash, always taking 2 stops inbetween ancient Alexandrias:
Alexandria HBE - Kandahar KDH - Khujad LBD - Termez TMJ

Comment: There are in fact nonstop flights from Washington DC (either DCA or IAD) to Washington State (SEA).  Still doesn't count, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge sure, but they did not pop up on my flight checker, so I could not include them...

Comment: The two mentioned Spanish cities have different names, one is named Santa Cruz de la Palma and the other is Santa Cruz de Tenerife. Those names have a common root but are not the same. Useless trivia: per law, no two municipalities can have the same name in Spain.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez "De La X" is a geographical location marker to differentiate different cities by the same name, it is like the "am Main" in "Frankfurt am Main", which is shortened to "Frankfurt (Main)".

Comment: Not in Spain, and definitely not in this case. Ask any Spaniard at random about Santa Cruz, and very few will know what you are talking about unless you specify the full name. I know, I'm Spanish myself.

Comment: Not sure where you got SFY from. SFY is Tri-Township Airfield in Savanna IL, not Springfield MA. There is no airport in Springfield MA. Westover Metropolitan CEF in Chicopee and Westfield-Barnes Regional BAF in Westfield are the nearest airports, neither of which has regularly scheduled flights. The nearest airports with regular flights are Hartford/Springfield Bradley International BDL in Windsor Locks CT and Worcester Regional ORH in Worcester MA, neither of which would ordinarily be listed as Springfield MA.

Answer (score 12):

The US low-cost airline Avelo is launching flights between [Wilmington, Delaware (ILG) and Wilmington, North Carolina (ILM).](https://6abc.com/amp/avelo-airlines-wilmington-airport-in-delaware-nonstop-flight-destinations-summer-vacation-plans/13160892/)

Answer (score 11):

Since your rules do not mention that flights have to be regular nor commercial, some "test flights" may satisfy yor criteria.

The ticket below was for a direct flight from Toulouse (TLS) to the very same Toulouse (TLS) airport, approx. 10 hours long just to reach the place you were departing from.

[image]

This was the first Airbus A340 flight with passengers, aimed at testing the cabin and its related facilities (intense use of toilets, heating and serving hundreds of meals, etc.). Except that you could not buy the ticket from an airline, it was just like a normal, fully booked, evening flight. You would pop up at the airport 1-2 hrs before, go through security, wait in the terminal and board the plane from a gate. During the flight, the plane just circled above the Pyrénées mountains to make time pass and burn its fuel. It then returned to its original airport in the morning (no jetlag!).

Comment: Technically the question does say "two cities".  Toulouse and Toulouse are one city.

Comment: I've also flown from Kiruna to Kiruna on a scientific flight, and many (most?) sightseeing flights start and end at the same place.  I admire your creativity, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: How did you manage to get that ticket then?

Comment: @NateEldredge Heraclitus ("everything flows") would contend that the Toulouse of 10 hours ago *was* in fact a different city ;-). Camel, great find. I would say this is an answer to the question the OP didn't even dare ask. (And I remember a satirical traveler's guide suggesting to take a domestic return flight from and to Charles de Gaulle because that was the fastest way between terminals...)

Comment: What's the point of taking the flight from place A to place A spending 10 hours on a plane? Even if it's free..

Comment: @kiradotee, it's kinda cool to test a brand new plane...

Comment: @masterX244 Tickets were mainly distributed to Airbus employees through a lottery. I don't remember exactly, but I guess press and a few external people were also invited.

Comment: Do flights for repositioning aircrafts count? Sometimes Air France takes a 777 from Paris Orly (ORY) to Paris Charles-De-Gaulle (CDG). Same city again, but two differents airports.

Answer (score 10):

Pfäffikon SZ and Pfäffikon ZH are two suburbs of Zürich, about 10km from each other. SZ (Schwyz) and ZH (Zürich) refer the the cantons these villages are in.
Both are on the Zürich suburban train network, and you can travel between them every half hour. At one time there were even direct trains...

Comment: The question specifies "flights".

Comment: OP indicates trains themselves, so I feel this answer is valid.

Comment: I thought the train example was mentioned just for contrast.  The last sentence of the question makes it very clear that the criteria are flights, not trains (note the word "but" and the boldface on "flights").

Answer (score 3):

First I'll propose one historic but concrete example [there used to be a helicopter shuttle between London (LHR) and London (LGW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlink_(helicopter_shuttle_service)) (same city, different airports).  I'm sure there were similar services in other countries.

Now for my attempts to find something current.  I don't believe there is anything, but can't claim to have conclusive proof.

From [Wikipedia's list of international airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_airports_by_country) I extracted all the airport names (pasted into a text editor, tidied up, piped through `sort`.  Of course at this point I may already be omitting some domestic airports like Portland(PWM)-Portland(PDX) as mentioned in the comments.
The full list is too long to include here but is [on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xts8rmvt3k1g1yu/airports_sorted.txt?dl=0).

Then I used a Python script to pare this down to duplicate city names, generate URLs for Google flights, and load those URLS (rate-limited) in the default browser:

```
    #data taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_airports_by_country
import codecs
import webbrowser
import time
airport_list=[]
duplicates=[]
testURLs=[]
base="https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt="
date1="2020-11-28"
end=".2020-12-02;c:GBP;e:1;sd:1;t:f"
with codecs.open('airports_sorted.txt', encoding='utf-8') as airports:
    for line in airports:
        airport_list.append(line.replace('\n','').split("\t"))
        
print ('%d total airports found'%len(airport_list))
for n,airport in enumerate(airport_list):
    for m,possible_duplicate in enumerate(airport_list):
        if airport[0]==possible_duplicate[0] and n!=m and airport[1] not in ([duplicate[1] for duplicate in duplicates]):#test for same city name, not same index, not same airport name
            duplicates.append(airport)
            testURL=base+airport[2]+"."+possible_duplicate[2]+"."+date1+"*"+airport[2]+"."+possible_duplicate[2]+end
            testURLs.append(testURL)
print ('%d airports with duplicate city names found'%len(duplicates))
print ('They are:')
print ('City\tAirport\tCode')
for duplicate in duplicates:
    print ('%s\t%s\t%s'%(duplicate[0],duplicate[1],duplicate[2]))

tab_count=0
for testURL in testURLs:
    print (testURL)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(testURL)
    tab_count+=1
    time.sleep(1)#load slowly
    if tab_count>9:
        dummy=input("press enter to continue")
        tab_count=0#load max 10 tabs at once
```

Leaving the following list of 70 airports:

```
Alexandria  Alexandria International Airport    ALY
Alexandria  Borg El Arab Airport    HBE
Bandung Husein Sastranegara International Airport   BDO
Bandung Kertajati International Airport KJT
Beijing Beijing Capital International Airport   PEK
Beijing Beijing Daxing International Airport    PKX
Birmingham  Birmingham International Airport    BHX
Birmingham  Birmingham-Shuttlesworth International Airport  BHM
Buenos Aires    Aeroparque Jorge Newbery    AEP
Buenos Aires    Ministro Pistarini International Airport    EZE
Chicago Chicago Midway International Airport    MDW
Chicago O'Hare International Airport    ORD
Colombo Bandaranaike International Airport  CMB
Colombo Ratmalana International Airport RML
Columbus (OH)   John Glenn Columbus International Airport   CMH
Columbus (OH)   Rickenbacker International Airport  LCK
Frankfurt   Frankfurt Airport   FRA
Frankfurt   Frankfurt-Hahn Airport  HHN
Houston George Bush Intercontinental Airport    IAH
Houston William P. Hobby Airport    HOU
Istanbul    Istanbul Airport    IST
Istanbul    Sabiha Gökçen International Airport SAW
Jakarta Halim Perdanakusuma International Airport   HLP
Jakarta Soekarno Hatta International Airport    CGK
Johannesburg    Lanseria International Airport  HLA
Johannesburg    OR Tambo International Airport  JNB
Kristiansand    Kristiansand Airport, Kjevik    KRS
Kristiansand    Kristiansund Airport, Kvernberget   KSU
Milan   Linate Airport  LIN
Milan   Malpensa Airport    MXP
Moscow  Domodedovo International Airport    DME
Moscow  Sheremetyevo International Airport  SVO
Moscow  Vnukovo Airport VKO
New York City   John F. Kennedy International Airport   JFK
New York City   LaGuardia Airport   LGA
Oslo    Oslo Airport-Gardermoen OSL
Oslo    Sandefjord Airport  TRF
Panama City Northwest Florida Beaches International Airport ECP
Panama City Tocumen International Airport   PTY
Paris   Charles de Gaulle Airport   CDG
Paris   Orly Airport    ORY
Reykjavik   Keflavik International Airport  KEF
Reykjavik   Reykjavik Airport   RKV
Rio de Janeiro  Rio de Janeiro–Galeão International Airport GIG
Rio de Janeiro  Santos Dumont Airport   SDU
São Paulo   São Paulo–Congonhas Airport CGH
São Paulo   São Paulo–Guarulhos International Airport   GRU
Seattle Kenmore Air Harbor Seaplane Base    LKE
Seattle King County International Airport   BFI
Seattle Seattle-Tacoma International Airport    SEA
Shanghai    Shanghai Hongqiao International Airport SHA
Shanghai    Shanghai Pudong International Airport   PVG
Singapore   Seletar Airport XSP
Singapore   Singapore Changi Airport    SIN
Stockholm   Stockholm-Arlanda Airport   ARN
Stockholm   Stockholm-Bromma Airport    BMA
Stockholm   Stockholm-Skavsta Airport   NYO
Stockholm   Stockholm-Västerås Airport  VST
Tehran  Imam Khomeini International Airport IKA
Tehran  Mehrabad International Airport  THR
Tenerife    Tenerife North Airport  TFN
Tenerife    Tenerife South Airport  TFS
Valencia    Arturo Michelena International Airport  VLN
Valencia    Valencia Airport    VLC
Victoria    Seychelles International Airport    SEZ
Victoria    Victoria International Airport  YYJ
Warsaw  Frédéric Chopin Airport WAW
Warsaw  Modlin Airport  WMI
Washington, D.C.    Ronald Reagan Washington National Airport** DCA
Washington, D.C.    Washington Dulles International Airport IAD
```

None of these pairs show anything on FlightRadar24's search of direct flights, but that only searches current flights. Google similarly doesn't find anything direct.  The best is Panama City (Panama, PTY) to Panama City (Florida, ECP) with a change in Houston.  Google should hopefully find everything direct, but it certainly misses some indirect routes: flightconnections.com finds Valencia (Spain, VLC) to Valencia (Venezuela, VLN) with 2 changes (several routes) but Google doesn't.

I won't claim this is conclusive for a couple of reasons:

- As I noted above it misses domestic airports (if there's a list of all airports in the world, I can try pointing my script at that).
- Some airports may serve more than one city, or not the city it's named for (e.g. Newark is generally thought of as serving New York).  That would be hard to code, but harder to define.
- This depends on the completeness and correctness of the list, which I can't vouch for.  I found one typo: KSU serves Kristians**u**nd not Kristians**a**nd, so there's a fake duplicate on my list; a typo with the opposite effect could hide a success.  Also ALY isn't an airport serving Alexandria.  It might have been in the past, or it might have been called AEX.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a direct train [041/042](https://rasp.yandex.ru/thread/R_041G_112) from [Veliky] Novgorod to [Nizhny] Novgorod and back.

And nobody is very happy about it since it messed up former city residents' arrival time to Moscow.

Comment: I wonder if [Novgorod Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novgorod_Airport) (NVR) ever had flights  to [Nizhny Novgorod International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strigino_International_Airport) (GOJ).

Comment: @gerrit The NVR airport no longer exists, there could be such flights in Soviet times, but GOJ was called Gorky back then so it won't count.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same name, but American flies from Charlotte Douglas International (CLT) in Charlotte, North Carolina to Cyril E. King Airport (STT) in Charlotte Amelie, U.S. Virgin Islands, though the latter is usually advertised as Saint Thomas, which is the island where Charlotte Amelie is located.